# After upgrade Flutter (3.13.9) stable channel My url strategy was changed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I just updated my flutter web app. No Big changes in the code, but suddenly my urlstrategy changes.

I did a downgrade in my pubspec.yaml, even the fact that there was not libraries related to routes neither something similar and the issue/behavior keep happens.

Any clue on that?

Flutter 3.13.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d211f42860 (8 days ago) • 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
Engine • revision 0545f8705d
Tools • Dart 3.1.5 • DevTools 2.25.0

BR

Rollback my pubspec.yaml to same of previous sw version.